# WPF C# Paging in Wrap Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, paging, wrappanel

i populated some text ( i name them as questions) from database but in my wrap panel i can only display 3 questions , the rest of the questions are being cut-off , i have more than 3 questions , how can i do a paging in wrap panel to display the rest of the question on the panel itself? i populate the questions by for loop like this:

```
 for( int i= 0 ; i<lstQuestion.Count()-2; i++)
        {
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock(); // Question 
            tb.FontSize = 19;
            tb.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            tb.Text = lstQuestion[i].QuestionContent;
            tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            wrapPanel1.Children.Add(tb);



            TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
            if (lstQuestion[i].Answer.Trim().Length > 0) // Textbox for user to input answer in every question
            {

                tbox.FontSize = 19;
                tbox.Width = 250;
                tbox.Height = 50;
                tbox.PreviewDrop += new DragEventHandler(tbox_PreviewDrop);
                tbox.Focusable = false; // Disallow user to input anything into it.
                wrapPanel1.Children.Add(tbox);
            }

            answers.Add(lstQuestion[i].Answer);

            if (lstQuestion[i].QuestionNo != lstQuestion[i + 1].QuestionNo) // add spacing between question
            {
                StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
                sp.Width = 1010;
                wrapPanel1.Children.Add(sp);
                Label spacing = new Label();
                spacing.Width = 1010;
                spacing.Content = "";
                wrapPanel1.Children.Add(spacing);
            }

        } // end of for each loop.
```

And in my xaml :

```
<Grid>
    <WrapPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="wrapPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Height="400" Width="1038" Margin="0,77,0,43" />
    <WrapPanel Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="wrapPanel2" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Background="Aquamarine" Width="1000">
    </WrapPanel>
    <Button Content="Check" Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="90"  FontSize="24" Margin="474,0" Click="button1_Click" />

</Grid>
```

Wrappanel1 is where i put my questions and textbox ( wrap panel 1 is the panel that i want to do paging in ) , wrappanel2 is another panel where choices of answers are there.

[image]

As you can see from the grey arrow , there is still more text , but it just stops there at the end of the scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Put your wrapPanel1 inside a `ScrollViewer`.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="400" Width="1038">
    <WrapPanel  Name="wrapPanel1" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Try arranging your UI in XAML with `RowDefinitions`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="wrapPanel2" Background="Aquamarine" Width="1000"></WrapPanel>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Height="400" Width="1038" CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <WrapPanel Name="wrapPanel1"/>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Check" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="90" FontSize="24" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: hi thanks for fast reply , does putting a scrollviewer enable all text to be seen? Yes , scrollviewer does work , but not all text are seen , only some but more then previously after using scrollviewer

Comment: I personally don't like arranging UI using Margins and static Height and Width. So try removing Margin from ScrollViewer and see if it works.

Comment: yeah i removed the Margin , the margin default-set whenever i remove it and run it again , it will re-appear

Comment: Is it ? Try removing it from property panel.

Comment: yup in the properties its 0

Comment: Interesting !! still you see Margin="0,77,0,43" in XAML ?

Comment: nope , i duno when it will apear again sometimes after i run, but it usually appear again but as long as i dun touch it , it remains the way i wanted , when i remove the Margin and put it to 0 , it doesn't change anything , i guess it is default

Comment: If you drag it in designer then it will definitely regenerated.

Comment: ic... so any idea why my text is still being cut-off? does it got to do with my text fontsize? or the static height and width

Comment: See my updated answer. This is how you can place controls in a Grid.

Comment: hey thanks for your updated , still didn't work tho , i tried using grid before , changing smaller font , setting height and width to auto , doesn't helps

Comment: Can you post a screenshot to describe it more ?

Comment: After checking screenshot I figured out that the ScrollViewer should be in second row so corrected that in answer. Also try to avoid setting Width in your code behind content.

Comment: i suppose , scrollviewer cannot be a row?  my scrollviewer becomes vertical

Comment: I meant ScrollViewer should be put in second row of parent Grid as I see in screenshot. What do you mean by becomes vertical ?

Comment: the scrollviewer now at the bottom of the wrap panel lying vertically